# Swift : Clear UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview

I'm using PNChart in a UIView and overtime my method runs it adds an addition line to the graph rather than recreating the entire graph. How do I clear a UIView, before add[ing]Subview?

```
     @IBOutlet weak var lineChart: UIView!


    ...
    // in function
    theLineChart.chartData = [actualData]
    theLineChart.strokeChart()
    // want to clear self.lineChart here
    self.lineChart.addSubview(theLineChart)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If by “clear” you mean remove all previously added subviews from it, you could try something like:

```
while let subview = lineChart.subviews.last {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

The caveat is that `lineChart` should remain a plain `UIView` (or your self-made subclass that you know the implementation of), as otherwise it may have internal subviews that you shouldn't remove.

Then again, if it is nothing but a plain `UIView`, you could simply replace the whole view with a new one (this might even make it simple to cross-fade between old and new views if such is desired).